# Flutter: _route == ModalRoute.of(context)': is not true on dialog

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
final _sectionFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

...
TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: _addSection,
              icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
              label: Text("open"),
            ),
...

_addSection() {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => PlatformAlertDialog(
        title: Text(translate("other_details.extra_sections")),
        content: Form(
          key: _sectionFormKey,
          child: Text(translate("other_details.extra_sections_info")),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: new PlatformText((translate('ok'))),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

If I click too fast on the button (one to show the dialog and again to close it clicking on the background) I get these errors:

> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/will_pop_scope.dart': Failed assertion:
> line 135 pos 12: '_route == ModalRoute.of(context)': is not true.
>
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line
> 4954 pos 14: '_dependents.isEmpty': is not true.
>
> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we
> should provide substantially more information in this error message to
> help you determine and fix the underlying cause.

Comment: what happen if you use  `Navigator.pop(context);` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please change your code to:
final _sectionFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

...
TextButton.icon(
              onPressed: _addSection,
              icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline_rounded),
              label: Text("open"),
            ),
...

_addSection() {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => PlatformAlertDialog(
        title: Text(translate("other_details.extra_sections")),
        content: Form(
          key: _sectionFormKey,
          child: Text(translate("other_details.extra_sections_info")),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: new PlatformText((translate('ok'))),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: onPressed: Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => _addSection()));